# Create a regex that returns an array

Tags: ruby, regex

I am working in Ruby. I need to create a regex that takes in a string, I suppose, and returns an array with only the words that start with `"un"` and end with `"ing"`. I have no clue how to do it :/

```
def words_starting_with_un_and_ending_with_ing(text)
  !!text.capitalize.scan(/\A+UN\Z+ING/)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def uning string
  string.scan(/\b[Uu]n[a-z]*ing\b/)
end
```

See [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-scan) for more info. For a nice interactive introduction to Regex take a look at [RegexOne](https://regexone.com/).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, agreed on both counts. Have updated answer ty.

Comment: Thanks for the website too, it looks like an excellent resource!